# ImportError Pandas in Jupiter notebook - Not looking at venv packages

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

I installed pandas via pip in my virtualenv venv.

When I run import pandas as pd, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-588656c123e4> in <module>
      3 import tarfile #2
      4 from six.moves import urllib #3
----> 5 import pandas as pd #4

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I am running Jupiter notebook in the virtual environment. To make sure it installed properly, I opened the python in the virtualenv and ran the import, and it worked fine, what could be the issue? Could it be that though I ran Jupiter Notebook in my venv its not looking at the packages in the virtual environment?

Edit 1: I installed pandas on my machine, not in the virtual machine, and that resolved my issue. However, I want the notebook to look at the packages in my virtual environment, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this in a Jupyter cell

```
!pip install pandas
```

Comment: which version of python you install? Make sure you you're installing pandas for the same version of python  (i.e `python x.x`) and running the program using the same `python version`

Comment: You can use `!python --version` to find out the python version you've installed; to make sure you're installing the package with same version, use `py -x.x -m pip install PACKAGENAME` (this will specifically for Python x.x version)

Comment: It is for Python 3.7.9, the same version of python I am using. The issue seems to be that the Jupiter notebook when executing doesn't refer to the site_packages in the virtual environment